# when is dgraph going to support Gremlin

Tags: dgraph

In the FAQ on the documentation site there is a question about Gremlin support: [When id dgrpah going to support gremlin](https://dgraph.io/docs/faq/#when-is-dgraph-going-to-support-gremlin)

The answer is `after v1.0` but as we're way past this version I was wondering if this is in the works or was abandoned altogether

Answer (score -1):

it looks like the plan from the 2019 roadmap was dropped in the 2020 roadmap. If, like me, you would like to see this happen: upvote [this comment](https://github.com/dgraph-io/dgraph/issues/4724#issuecomment-581588668)